# Is there an alternative for vs Nuget Package Manager?

Tags: nuget

Nuget command line does not have all useful features, like upgrading package version if other library requires higher version.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Paket](http://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/) is a great alternative to NuGet.

Everything works from command line. Although, if you want, you can also install the [Paket for Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ce104917-e8b3-4365-9490-8432c6e75c36).

It works with regular NuGet feeds. You'll have to convert your `packages.config` files to Paket's format though.

It has a `convert-from-nuget` command to convert them from NuGet.

Comment: I agree -- paket is a great tool and easier to work with than NuGet.

Comment: But has no support for running scripts on install, should you want that. Some people like that, some dont...

Comment: It's this still true? Or now Paket is based on Nuget? Thanks!